# Dialogflow capture all the user voice input

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home

I am making a casual conversational action with DialogFlow.

One of the problems I experienced, is that the assistant do not let me (user) finish talk. If I have a very long answer, he is too hasty in give an answer, and does not me (user) say everything I want to say.

Does anybody know how to control the amount of silent time (for for example do a small pause on user input, real people need to breath) on DialogFlow.